# What is the best way to repeat the same pull request but with different author name?

Tags: git, github

I made a good pull request but I need to change the author name for some identity verification. I tried to do

```
git add path/to/file
```

To make a new commit, however since I didn't change the files they are not getting added to the new commit. Is there a way I can get around git not adding my files to the commit? Otherwise can I use the same commit and make a new pull request now that I've changed the author name?

Comment: Unclear what the question is. Are you asking how make an empty commit? Or do you want to replace all the commits? Or what?

Comment: If you need to change the author name in the commit itself, you can amend the commit and force push it.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

You probably want `git commit --amend --reset-author`, as in [joanis' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71725000/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeat-the-same-pull-request-but-with-different-author-n#comment126762203_71725000), but with the `--reset-author` option added.  (Be sure to set your `user.name` and/or `user.email` as desired first.)  This will require using `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease` to update your GitHub fork, after which GitHub automatically updates your PR.

## Long

There are two (or more, depending on how you count) parts to this:

- there's the Git part, and
- there's the GitHub (or other hosting site, but you used [github](/questions/tagged/github) so we'll assume GitHub here) part.

Both parts include one overriding principle of all things Git: Git is all about *commits*.  Commits are:

- numbered (by hash ID);
- immutable (the hash ID is actually a cryptographic checksum of the commit's content); and
- made up of two parts: *metadata* and a *snapshot*.  The metadata contains stuff like the name and email address of the commit's author.

In your case you appear to like everything about the existing commit(s) *except* that the "author" name in the metadata is not what you want.

Unfortunately, since every commit is immutable, you can't fix the existing commit(s).  Fortunately, since Git is greedy for *new* commits, you can simply make new ones.

If you have just one commit to "fix" (replace with a new-and-improved one with a different hash ID), you can use the method that [joanis mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71725000/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeat-the-same-pull-request-but-with-different-author-n#comment126762203_71725000), namely `git commit --amend`.  If you have more than one commit that you need to improve this way, you need a more powerful tool, such as `git rebase` or `git cherry-pick`.  On the assumption that you have just *one* commit to fix, we'll look only at using `git commit --amend`.

Now, the option `--amend` seems to claim that this is going to alter some existing commit.  But that's literally impossible.  It won't do that.  It's important to realize this, and to understand what it does instead.  To get there, let's look at what a *normal* `git commit` (without `--amend`) does first.

#### A regular commit "on a branch"

When we use Git, we generally start with `git clone` to copy all the commits from some existing repository.  This gets us a *new* repository—one that *we* control, vs the original that we don't—but does not get us the *branch names* from the original repository.  (GitHub will add a wrinkle to this when we get to using GitHub's "fork".)

That is, if they have branches `main` and `develop` and `feature/short`, and we clone their repository, we end up with *remote-tracking names*, `origin/main`, `origin/develop`, and `origin/feature/short`.  These things are *our* Git's way of remembering *their* Git's *branch* names.  Our repository has *its own independent branch names*.  We get the *commits* from them, and our copies are bit-for-bit identical to their copies of the commits, so the *commits* are effectively shared.  But the *branch names* aren't.

As our `git clone` finishes up, it does one last thing: it *checks out* some branch, *creating a new branch name*.  The act of "checking out a branch" in Git is allowed to create a new name, or use some existing names, but `git clone` didn't make any branches so this *has* to create a new name.  But hang on, what exactly *is* a branch name anyway?  To understand *this*, we have to go back to the commits:

- the commits are numbered, by hash ID; but
- the hash IDs *appear* random and are not useful to humans.

Meanwhile, each commit has both a snapshot and metadata, and in the metadata for any one commit, we find a list—usually just one element long—of *other* Git commit hash IDs.  In the normal case of a single element, that one hash ID is the hash ID of this particular commit's *parent* commit: the commit that comes *just before* this commit.  So these hash IDs form a backwards-looking chain.  If we can just tell Git the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain, Git can use the stored parent ID of that commit to find the second-from-last commit.  The second-from-last commit stores the hash ID of the third-from-last commit, which stores the hash ID of the fourth-from-last commit, and so on down the line:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

if `H` stands in for the hash ID of the last commit.  So in Git, the *branch name* is simply a way to have *Git* store hash ID `H` (the real one, in all its ugliness, not the simplified letter `H`).  If we're on branch `main`, then the *name* `main` stores hash ID `H` for us:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

Now, all parts of every commit are immutable: nothing, not even Git itself, can change the files *stored in* commit `H`.  Furthermore only Git can *read* those files: the other programs on your computer can't even read these things, much less write on them.  But to get work done, we have to be able to read our files, and also change them.  So the act of *checking out* a branch like `main` means:

- Hey Git, find the name `main`.  It points to some commit hash ID.
- Go look up that commit.  Find all the files stored inside that commit.
- *Extract* all those files into ordinary read/write files that I can work with.

Git attaches the special name `HEAD` to that branch name, so that even if there are other commits for other branches and other branch names or remote-tracking names remembering those hash IDs, Git knows which branch name we're using:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
      \
       I--J   <-- origin/develop, origin/feature/short
```

for instance.  Note how more than one name can select the same commit.  If we create our own new branch name now, such as `feature/arturo`, we'll get this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), feature/arturo, origin/main
      \
       I--J   <-- origin/develop, origin/feature/short
```

If we now *check out* that name, we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, feature/arturo (HEAD), origin/main
      \
       I--J   <-- origin/develop, origin/feature/short
```

That is, we're still *using* commit `H`.  We're just doing so through our new *name* now.

If we now make a new commit (by the usual *modify some files, run `git add`, and run `git commit` sequence), Git will package up a new snapshot into a new commit—which gets a new unique hash ID, which we'll call `K`—and write all this out.  In the metadata for the *new* commit, Git will store the hash ID for the *current* commit:

```
          K
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, feature/arturo (HEAD), origin/main
      \
       I--J   <-- origin/develop, origin/feature/short
```

and now Git pulls its special trick that makes branch names actually work: Git writes the *new commit's hash ID* (which we're calling `K`) into the *current branch name*, so that the branch name now points to commit `K`:

```
          K   <-- feature/arturo (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
      \
       I--J   <-- origin/develop, origin/feature/short
```

That's the process of making new commits in the normal way.

#### Using `git commit --amend`

It's literally impossible to change any existing commit, but we can always make a *different* new commit.  The usual way would be to modify some file and `git add` and `git commit` again:

```
          K--L   <-- feature/arturo (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
      \
       I--J   <-- origin/develop, origin/feature/short
```

but that would give you two commits on your branch, when you just want an "improved" version of existing commit `K`.  That is, you'd like new commit `L` to point back to commit `H`, and just re-use the existing snapshot.

If you run a `git commit` without any options, Git will complain that there's nothing to commit.  What Git is doing here is noticing that if it made a new *snapshot*, the new commit would exactly match the *current* snapshot.  Git sees no point in doing this.  Adding `--allow-empty`—a misnomer; no commit is ever truly *empty*—would force Git to do that, but that's still wrong as new commit `L` will point back to existing commit `K`: not what you want.

Using `git commit --amend`, however, tells Git: *I really want to make a new commit now, even if I have not updated the snapshot; and furthermore, I want the *parent* of the new commit to be, not the current commit, but rather the current commit's parent commit*.  That is, Git should do this:

```
          K   ???
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
      \  \
       \  L   <-- feature/arturo (HEAD)
        \
         I--J   <-- origin/develop, origin/feature/short
```

The old commit `K` does not *go away*.  It's still there in your repository.  If you have memorized its hash ID, you can use that to see it.  But Git makes new commit `L` such that its *parent* is commit `H`, the same as `K`'s parent.  Then Git sticks the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name as usual.

This means when Git goes to look up the name `feature/arturo`, it finds the hash ID of `L`, which gets it commit `L`, which leads Git on back to commit `H`, which leads back to commit `G`, and so on.  Using the *name*, you no longer *see* commit `K` at all.  It's *as if* commit `K` had changed.  It hasn't—it's still the same as it always was—but unless you've memorized hash IDs, it *seems* as though it changed into commit `L`.

#### The `--reset-author` flag

When you *do* use `git commit --amend`, Git tries to *re-use* as much of the previous commit's metadata as it can.  That is, Git's default assumption is that what you're doing is fixing up the *snapshot*, and that the existing metadata is probably mostly OK.

A Git commit actually has *two* <name, email-address, date-and-time> stamps in it.  One of these gives the *author* of the commit: the person who wrote it originally.  The second one names the *committer:* the person who is adding this commit to this Git repository.  The reason for this separation is that in the early days of Git—and still today for some projects, such as the Git repository for Git itself—people did a lot of emailing of patches, with incremental revisions.  That is, someone would make an initial stab at fixing a problem or adding a new feature, perhaps using one commit or perhaps using many.  Then they'd convert the commit(s) to email messages using `git format-patch` and email them to a mailing list with `git send-email`.  The mailing list would discuss the proposed patches, perhaps spend a few weeks [bikeshedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality) ([additional](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding)), and so on.  Finally, the maintainer—the person with the "main" Git repository for the project—would apply the consensus commits to that repository.  The maintainer would be the "committer" and the original author of the changes the "author".

When you use `git commit --amend`, Git will *always* make a new *committer* line for the new commit.  This will use your configured `user.name` and `user.email` settings (and the current date-and-time).  But Git will retain the original commit's *author* information (name, email, date-and-time).  Adding `--reset-author` tells Git: *use my configuration for author name and email, and the current date-and-time, to set the authorship of the new commit*.

(Note that you can also use `--author` and `--date`, but `--reset-author` is generally the way to go here.)

#### GitHub adds complications

The above describes the process you might use in a private or corporate setup, though corporate setups vary so this might not be the one *your* company uses.  That is, in the above setup, there's some GitHub-side repository that you control, and you clone it—or already have a clone of it—on your laptop, or whatever.  You do your work on your laptop, and then run `git push` to send new commits to the clone that exists on GitHub.

In a lot of cases, though, you may only have *read* access to the original GitHub repository.  In order to submit a pull request, you must use GitHub's "fork" notion.  Here, GitHub provide, on their web pages, a button labeled <kbd>FORK</kbd> for some project.  You click that button and *poof*, GitHub make you a GitHub-side clone *of* that project, that you own.  That is, you now have a new GitHub repository of your own, named after the original project's repository.

This GitHub-side clone has several special properties that `git clone` does not give you:

- First, when GitHub do this kind of internal fork, they make sure it saves space in *their* computers.  Your new fork takes very little space and time on their systems.  That doesn't help *you* any, but it makes it cheap for GitHub to offer the feature.  (The way this works is that since commits are immutable, their software doesn't really *copy* anything, it just *shares* the commits.)
- Second, this clone not only copies all the *commits* from the original repository, it *also* copies all the *branch names*.  So unlike a `git clone`-made clone, where you get the commits but no branches, you get their commits *and* their branch names.
- Last, and most important to you, GitHub set up your new GitHub-side clone—your "fork"—so that you can easily make *pull requests* to whoever owns the repository you just forked.

In other words, Pull Requests are specific to GitHub.  They're not something *Git* provides.  Other hosting sites (Bitbucket and GitLab for instance) have something very similar; Bitbucket even call theirs "pull requests", though GitLab call theirs "merge requests".  But they're all slightly different, so it's important to keep in mind whose hosting system you're using.

In any case, other than these three special features, your fork on GitHub is like any other Git repository anywhere.  Since it's *your* fork, you now control access *to* it.  (Don't forbid your own access!  I believe GitHub will let you do that, but it's not useful.)  You can `git clone` *this* repository to your laptop, and you'll get all the commits and none of the branches, as usual.

So, suppose you've done the fork-and-clone and you now have, on your laptop:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

You make a new branch and switch to it, still using commit `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, new-thing (HEAD), origin/main
```

You then make a new *commit:*

```
          I   <-- new-thing (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
```

You run `git push origin new-thing`, which has your Git package up your new commit `I` and send it to your GitHub fork, and ask GitHub to create a new branch name `new-thing` in your fork, pointing to new commit `I`.  So they do that:

```
          I   <-- new-thing
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

(note that they don't have an `origin/main`—they do not do this remote-tracking thing—and we do not care which branch name is their `HEAD`, though it's probably `main`; you can change this with the GitHub web interface).

Now you use GitHub's *pull request* feature, on their web page.  This makes your new commit `I` available to the GitHub-side repository from which you forked, generating a PR in *their* GitHub-side repository.  GitHub send mail to the owners of the original repository.  The owners can then inspect your commit `I` and ask you to fix things.  Perhaps, for instance, they asked you to change the author (or maybe you just decided to do this yourself).

Again, *no commit can ever be changed*.  You can't actually *fix* commit `I`.  But you can make a new and improved commit that's just *like* `I` only different, with whatever fix you want.  You do this on your laptop with `git commit --amend`, result in:

```
          I   <-- origin/new-thing
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          J   <-- new-thing (HEAD)
```

Note that your laptop Git is remembering your GitHub fork Git's `new-thing`, pointing to commit `I`, as your `origin/new-thing`.

If you now run:

```
git push -u origin new-thing     # the -u is optional and we won't go into it more
```

your Git will send your commit `J` to your GitHub fork, asking them (GitHub) politely to update their name `new-thing` to point to commit `J`, not commit `I`.  Now there is a problem, because their Git is greedy for commits.  If their Git were to update *their* `new-thing`, they would end up with:

```
          I   ???
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          J   <-- new-thing
```

This is, of course, exactly what you *want* them to do, but they will say *No, if I do that, I'll lose commit `I`!*  (It will still be there, they just won't be able to find it, so that counts as "losing" it.)  Your Git will say:

```
! [rejected]    new-thing -> new-thing (non-fast-forward)
```

which is Git's peculiar way to say "they object to losing some commits".

You *want* this to happen!  You need to *command* them to do it, despite the "lose commit `I`" thing.  This requires `git push --force` or (somewhat safer but longer to type) `git push --force-with-lease`:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin new-thing
```

That will force the Git over on GitHub to take your new `J` that replaces `I` and put it into place on your `new-thing` branch.

GitHub now automatically update your existing PR.  Other sites might require additional action at this point, but if you're using GitHub here, you are now done.